# Short INSERT query hangs on DataFileRead

Tags: postgresql

I have a short insert query with just a few joins. It takes around ~1 second to run.

Recently I am facing an issue where the query hangs and never finishes.

Querying on `pg_stat_activity` I see that it is in an **active** state. While refreshing the query I used on `pg_stat_activity`, I see the `PID` of the query is changing between `wait_event` and `wait_event_type` being both `NULL` to being `DataFileRead` and `IO`, respectively, and back again.

I wanted to see how long the query will hang, the longest I got to was an hour and 30 minutes, I terminated it since I wanted to continue to work.

Also, it doesn't always hang. It will sometime finish successfully (and fast) and sometimes hang. No other user is querying on this table, and the DB is used only by me and another person, so there are no locks or heavy load (I checked multiple times).

Any ideas on how to better investigate what is blocking this query from finishing?

Comment: "A few joins" could easily produce many millions of rows for some parameters and just a few for others.  That would be the simplest explanation and the first thing to rule out.  Is the "sometimes fast" with identical parameters?

Comment: Yes, running the same insert with identical parameters sometimes finishes in 1 seconds normally, but sometimes will hang.

Comment: At that point I'd use OS tools to see what is actually going on.  On Linux, `top` is a good place to start to see how much is io wait and how much CPU (If it were almost all io, then pg_stat_activity should almost never show anything else, while you do report seeing NULLs quite often. `top` should give you a more quantitative read).  And `strace -y -ttt -T -p <pid>` to see what files it is actually reading from when it blocks.  Index files?  data files?

Answer (score 0):

According to that `wait_event`, the cause is a slow disk. You'll have to figure out if the problem is in the hardware or configuration or whether it is just overloaded by concurrent activity.